# NetworkManager vpn basic authentication issue on centos7

Tags: vpn, centos-7, cisco-vpn-client, networkmanager

I'm using gui vpn(cisco) on centos7 by NetworkManager package, after an OS update I faced an issue when try to connect vpn,here is log: 
`Server 'nl.cisadd2.com' requested Basic authentication which is disabled by default`

(update) Log file:
[cislog.txt](http://s2.picofile.com/d/8370738668/4456d3ff-8e26-47ca-9da6-4e98d5116b4f/cislog.txt)

Comment: Are you using Cisco AnyConnect ?

Comment: @Mahesh yes I do

Comment: Can you upload the logs at a file sharing server and share the link ?

Comment: @Mahesh  Updated...

Comment: I am asking AnyConnect logs which should be part of System.log file.

Comment: @Mahesh attached buddy...